# Simple question about cyclic submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a ring, $A$ an $R$-module, $a \in A$. Then the cyclic submodule $C$ generated by $a$ is $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Here I am using the definition of a cyclic (sub)module as being the intersection of all submodules of $A$ containing the element $a$.

I am comfortable with
$$\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \bigcap_{\overset{\text{$F$ s.m. A}}{F \,\ni\, a}} F.$$
I am now trying to show
$$\bigcap_{\overset{\text{$F$ s.m. A}}{F \,\ni\, a}} F \subseteq \{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.\qquad(1)$$

My strategy has been to show that $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a submodule of $A$ and that $a \in \{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ which will give the result I want $(1)$. I have shown that $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $A$ and that 
$$a \in \{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$
What I am trying to show now is that if $r\in R$ then 
$$r(sa+na) \in \{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}.$$
As $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is to use the same module operation as $A$ and $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $A$ we have
$$r(sa+na)=r(sa)+r(na)=(rs)a+(nr)a$$
the problem I am having is that to be in $\{ra +na \mid r\in R,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, I would want $nr \in \mathbb{Z}$. So it looks like this method isn't going to work or can I salvage this somehow?

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you find "cyclic submodule"? I couldn't find it in Rowen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the method will work. You are already done since $r(sa+na)=(rs+rn)a + 0a$ is in the set, seeing that $rs+rn$ is in $R$.